# Multi-column file parsing with python

Tags: python

I have a data file with tab separated three data columns (and some repetitive header lines) as:

```
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\NP_416485.4 alignment. Using default output format...

#jjhgjg
0   0.89    u-p
1   -5.79   --- 
2   0.85    yui
3   0.51    uio
4   0.66    -08
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\YP_986467.7 alignment. Using default output format...

#gfhhjgjhg
0   0.001   -s-
1   0.984   ---
2   0.564   -fg
3   0.897   -sr
```

From the second data column, for those value(s) which are more than 0.5, I want to extract the corresponding first column number (or range).

For the above Input, the output would be:

```
NP_416485.4: 1, 3-5
YP_986467.7: 2-4
```

Here, "NP_416485.4" and "YP_986467.7" are from header descriptor (after \Programs). (Note that, the actual value for "NP_416485.4" for example, should be, "NP_416485.4: 0, 2-4", but I increases all of them with +1 as I dont want to start with 0).
As suggested by, to start with, I have used python csv module as:

```
import csv

with open('test.txt','rb') as tsvin, open('new.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
 csvout = csv.writer(csvout)

    for row in tsvin:
        count = float(row[1])
        if count > 0.5:
            csvout.writerow(row)
```

but it gives:

```
count = float(row[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Well, they are actually TSV files. You can use `csv` module to read them and create a lookup function to get what you need.

Comment: One word – `pandas`

Comment: Your xrange(count) makes no sense (what's the range of 0.63?), don't you just want to write the row, csvout.write(row).

Comment: I changed it to : csvout.writerow(row), but still it shows float to string conversion error

Comment: `print(repr(row[1]))` before you convert it to float and see what's the value.

Comment: i'm sorry.. I could not get it